# HTTP Connection refused to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I'm trying to make a login HTTP request from the frontend (Angular app) to AWS EC2 instance but it ends up with (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED) error.

This would be probably a security group policy issue (from the internet) but correct me if I'm wrong. It was working perfectly before and got this error in a few days. If anyone can help me solve this problem.

I tried to resolve this issue by configuring security group inbound rules with specific port number but port textbox will be disabled when I select HTTP request type. I added a snap of it. Kindly correct me if I'm wrong in detecting the problem so I can make a solution for it.

[image]

Comment: you need to add custom tcp option and then add your custom port number

Comment: I did but that won't resolve my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can also be due to the service not listening on the port that you are trying to connect to or not started or present. May be if the server running on the AWS instance if listening (and serving) to localhost or 127.0.0.1 / interface can also ignore connections from outside in which case it should be ensured the service listens on the appropriate external address.

AWS also checks to detect abuse. If somehow, some unknown applications maliciously got inside your EC2 instances due to publicly open port and triggered some unknown/malicious traffic, then in that case also AWS can block/shutdown those ports.

Comment: Is there any logging functionality EC2 offers through which it shows type of traffic. I will take action if traffic is malicious.

Comment: Actually the project is in a container and container was stopped that's why it got this error but after I start the container again the same issue arises.

Comment: There are EC2 IDS/IPS solutions that help in alerting of malicious activity and policy violations. It also helps in identification and taking of action as well against traffic.  EC2 also supports Traffic Mirroring service that enables one to have a copy, network traffic from an EC2 and have the traffic content inspection, threat monitoring or troubleshooting performed..

Answer (score 1):

**You can also try to add All Traffic Type in EC2 -> Security Groups -> Inbound rules -> Edit inbound rules like this:**

[image]

**You can use this method for testing purposes initially, and later, you can add custom IP addresses or explore any better alternatives you may have.**

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused error means it passed the security group and reached the server, so its definitely not a security group issue

Usually, this is related to the web server is down, maybe due to server restart, or process crash.

try restarting your webserver and check again

Comment: Would there be any issue by restarting the server?

Comment: Nope, its standard process

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of you web server:

check nginx status

```
sudo systemctl status nginx

# if errors found reload:

service nginx reload
```

for apache

```
sudo systemctl status httpd

# restart if errors found:

sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

if you found nothing wrong check the log messages at **/var/log**